# How can I get rid of these shadows on my text in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, shadow

If you go to http://mattculbreth.com or http://mattculbreth.com/projects.html in IE <= 8, you'll see shadows around the text.  Safari, Chrome, and FireFox all render this correctly.

From looking at the CSS, can anyone tell how to make this look better in IE?  IE 9 looks ok (but it doesn't get the gradients, which I'm fine with).

**Edit 1:**  I got this template from a designer.  It uses the latest in CSS magic so I'm not shocked by less than perfect IE performance here.  The CSS files are [here](http://mattculbreth.com/css/theme.css) and [here](http://mattculbreth.com/css/blueprint/screen.css) and [here](http://mattculbreth.com/css/mc.css).

Thanks a lot!

Matt

Comment: Why do you have all those `text-shadow` instructions in there in the first place?

Comment: I think you need to show your .css files contents to get help here.

Comment: @Mark they're linked. This is really strange.

Comment: If I right click, and convert to PDF, it shows OK (using IE8 in compatibility mode.) otherwise, it is really hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit #1: Remove all the "FILTER: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(...);" attributes from your theme.css file and you are good to go.

Comment: maybe this one> hard to tell for sure -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0px, OffY=0px, Color='#cccccc')";

Comment: Perhaps remove them one at a time, but those filters will only "work" in IE anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's being generated by `theme.css`, the a few classes apply the `dropShadow` filter, including `.box`, `.navwrap`, `P.link A`, and more. I can't quite figure out which one is actually causing the drop shadow, as they shouldn't be applied. You can play around with removing them to see which fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `text-shadow` properties from all your CSS files should do the trick.  My theory is that even though it gets overridden in mc.css, IE9.js is being ambitious and applying it.